# Recursive File Search Using the Dir() Function

Tags: vba

There are plenty of examples of using the FileSystemObject to recursively search for a file in subfolders.  I thought that it would be interesting to write one using the Dir() function.

I was wondering if there is a way to return the found file without using the extra `FoundFile` parameter?

---

```
Function FindFile(ByVal folderName As String, ByVal FileName As String, Optional ByRef FoundFile As String) As String
    Dim search As String
    Dim dirList As New Collection

    If Not Right(folderName, 1) = "\" Then folderName = folderName & "\"
    search = Dir(folderName & "\*", vbDirectory)
    While Len(search) > 0
        If Not search = "." And Not search = ".." Then
            If GetAttr(folderName & search) = 16 Then
                dirList.Add folderName & search
            Else
                If LCase(search) = LCase(FileName) Then
                    FoundFile = folderName & FileName
                    FindFile = FoundFile
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If

        End If
        search = Dir()
    Wend

    Dim fld
    For Each fld In dirList
        If Len(FoundFile) > 0 Then
            FindFile = FoundFile
            Exit Function
        Else
            FindFile = FindFile(CStr(fld), FileName, FoundFile)
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove it from parameter,
and make it a variable.

```
Function FindFile(ByVal folderName As String, ByVal FileName As String) As String
    Dim search As String
    Dim dirList As New Collection

    If Not Right(folderName, 1) = "\" Then folderName = folderName & "\"
    search = Dir(folderName & "\*", vbDirectory)
    While Len(search) > 0
        If Not search = "." And Not search = ".." Then
            If GetAttr(folderName & search) = 16 Then
                dirList.Add folderName & search
            Else
                If LCase(search) = LCase(FileName) Then
                    FindFile = folderName & FileName
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If

        End If
        search = Dir()
    Wend

    Dim fld
    Dim FoundFile As String
    For Each fld In dirList

        FoundFile = FindFile(CStr(fld), FileName)
        If Len(FoundFile) > 0 Then
            FindFile = FoundFile
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next


End Function
```

Comment: Very nice.  Why didn't I think of that?